# Why isn't my service connecting my components, Angular 5?

Tags: angular, service, angular5

I need to pass data from two unrelated components, they aren't parent-child or siblings. I've tried using services that have already been built to pass the data and I have tried building a new service to pass the data, but I keep running into errors or the data comes up null. While researching, it looked like at one point an option may be to updated from Angular 5 to a later version, but I am not sure if it is worth it time-wise to update the whole project to solve one issue. There are similar services in the project that are used for Modals, but that is not an option for these components.

drop.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Injectable()
export class DropService {

private selectedDropSource = new Subject<any>();
selectedDrop$ = this.selectedDropSource.asObservable();


}
```

drop-details.component.ts

```
  providers: [
   ...
    SelectedClientService,
    DropService
  ],

}) 
constructor(
...
              private dropService: DropService){
...

    //this is where the service needs to pass data
  backToDropListScreen(displayMessage: string){

    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: displayMessage,
        accept: () => {
             this.routes.navigate(['/management/']);
             
        }
    });


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Of note...

providers: [
...
SelectedClientService,
DropService
],

Any service declared **inside** the component, the way you are doing it, will create a new service for **each** component.
If what you are trying to do is to have one shared service, delete the *DropService* from the component providers and add *@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })* to your *DropService* or declare it in your providers in the module.

You will still DI the service in the component constructor like you have done.

Comment: Thanks! This is for Angular 5, does @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) work for Angular 5?

Comment: Apparently it began in Angular 6, which means that you will have to instead add it to your module in the providers section. Just so long as it's out of the component providers.
https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services